# Why is a report, in SSRS, when viewed in preview mode looks different when viewed in print layout mode?

Tags: reporting-services

I have a report that was originally built in report builder and then imported into Visual Studio to add some other formating to it. The report has a header and a body section. In the body section there is a column that shows commission and the commission is subtotaled for each sales person. There is a page break for each sales person as well. When I preview the report, the subtotal appears as it should for each sales person, but when I either look at it in print layout mode or send it to the printer, the subtotal appears in the body section of the next page, which is the next sales person. Why is it behaving like this and how can I fix this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The rendering for the "report viewer" and printing, pdf export, and other renderings are different. You'll have to change the layout so that it fits your desired render target. In this case printing.

Check your report and make sure nothing is outside of the print margins.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, it is almost impossible to get the Print render and the Report render to be identical.